# Transformar bucle while en bucle foreach

Tags: php, mysql

Necesito convertirlo al formato ***foreach***

```
$query = "SELECT id_prod FROM productos WHERE nombre_prod='$nombre' OR descrip='$caract' "; 
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

while ($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $id_producto = ($mostrar['id_prod']); 
}
```

Comment: ¿Se podría saber cuál es la finalidad de querer hacer eso? Es porque no necesitas mostrar los datos dentro del `while`, sino en otro sitio?

Answer (score 0):

No puedes listar usando mysql_fetch_array sin usar un while o un for ya que mysql fetch array trabaja con registros de uno en uno y no con un arreglo de registros que es lo necesario para trabajar con foreach. Si necesitas obligatoriamente el foreach aquí te muestro una adaptación a tu código:

```
$query = "SELECT id_prod FROM productos WHERE nombre_prod='$nombre' OR descrip='$caract' "; 
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$registros = array();
while ($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $registros[] = $mostrar; 
}

foreach($registros as $mostrar){ 

    $id_producto = $mostrar['id_prod'];

}
```